# Excel macro advice

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following macro running on a workbook to copy data with a specific criteria from "Master" sheet to "Quarantined" sheet;

```
Dim LR As Long, LR2 As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

With Sheets("Quarantined")
    LR2 = .Range("L" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    If LR2 > 2 Then
        .Range("A3:I" & LR2).ClearContents
    End If
End With

With Sheets("Master")
    LR = .Cells(Rows.Count, 8).End(xlUp).Row
    LR2 = Sheets("Quarantined").Range("L" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    With .Range("L2:L" & LR)
        .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="QUARANTINED"
        .Offset(1).Resize(LR).EntireRow.Copy Sheets("Quarantined").Range("A" & LR2 + 1)
        .AutoFilter
    End With
End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

It works perfectly but if I update the master and run the macro again it pastes it under the original information on the quarantined sheet. How do I get it to overwrite the information that was already there instead of pasting underneath?

Here's hoping

Answer (score 2):

It is pasting under the original info because you are telling it to.

You are clearing your range from `.Range("A3:I" & LR2).ClearContents` but you are taking the next available row from Col L `LR2 = Sheets("Quarantined").Range("L" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row`

Either Change your code to this

`.Range("A3:L" & LR2).ClearContents`

or take the last row based on Col A instead of Col L

Comment: Thank you. That has solved it. I must admit to being a bit new Ro this and that was a copy and paste, with a bit of modification ,of the code that I thought was right. Thanks again.